# How to show a label when a user inputs an unsupported value in a text field?

Tags: sql, sqlite, javafx

I am setting up a database and I need to know if a user inputs a wrong value by showing a label. My database supports only char (1 length) and I want when a user inputs any char more than 1 length a label shows invalid input or something, how do I catch such error or exception?

I have tried catching exceptions, but I want a more specific approach cause catching SQLExceptions just catches all possible errors

When I input an invalid value this error shows:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to
>   constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: customer.age)

Comment: a char has always the length of 1. What you mean is in SQLite maybe the text Type. Which is actually a text. For Validation you should make at first a user client validation, which check general if the validation is correct. But you also should check in Backend before you accept the values.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a TextFormatter to restrict the `TextField` to one character.

Comment: Another option is to return true if an SQLExceptions is thrown and false if not. Then you can use an `if-statement` to show a dialog.

Comment: thanks, i was actually so concern about catching the error from the sql backend that i forgot javafx could easily put constraints on the textfield that returns error when the input is greater than one character.. Thanks for the tip @Sedrick

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do (in the database) is an INSERT trigger with an INSTEAD OF option.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
   ON table_name
BEGIN
   your SQL code here
END;
```

It will replace the actual insert statement and you can manipulate the actual data with the NEW table.

```
IF LENGTH(NEW.string) > 1 THEN --INSERT my label
```

Else you can control the string length in your application.